# Is there a way to share video with SLComposeViewController fb and twitter

Tags: ios, facebook, swift, twitter

I need to allow users to share video and images to fb and twitter. I recently found the SLComposeViewController but it seems there is only an addImage method and no addVideo method. I'd really like to use the SLComposeViewController to share video because I'm on a tough time constraint. This is what I have so far and it works but there is no addVideo method:

```
var shareToTwitter : SLComposeViewController = SLComposeViewController(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeTwitter)
    shareToTwitter.setInitialText("initial text")
    //shareToTwitter.addImage(UIImage(named: "32.png"))

    self.presentViewController(shareToTwitter, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I'd really like to have the same sharing feature like instagram does. Is this possible with the SLComposeViewController?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SLComposeViewController is only used for share text and image now, it cannot be used for share video, maybe in the future it can share video if Apple want to do it.

Now you can use twitter's [the uploading media new API](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/post/media/upload-chunked) to share video to twitter.

I made a convenient class to make post video to twitter more easily.

Please check this: https://github.com/liu044100/SocialVideoHelper

You just need to call this class method.

```
+(void)uploadTwitterVideo:(NSData*)videoData account:(ACAccount*)account withCompletion:(dispatch_block_t)completion;
```

Hope it can resolve your problem.

Best Regards.

Comment: is there a way to use this to upload images to Facebook as well?

Comment: @劉雨辰 do you know how to add a description etc. to a facebook video using the methods in SocialVideoHelper?

Comment: @horsejockey I does not try it, may be something like this by replace the same method in SocialVideoHelper : https://gist.github.com/liu044100/f458d86ee0c23284c3ab

Comment: @劉雨辰 I was out of the office but I just tested it and it works like a dream! Thanks!

Comment: If I have not added a twitter account in the device settings. How could login with a pop up and also keep using this tool

Comment: You can use the method `+(BOOL)userHasAccessToTwitter` to check whether a twitter account in the device settings, if no account, you can show a pop up tell user set account in settings.

Answer (score 1):

Private method but works. Also you can share video to fb via default UIActivityViewController.

```
@import Foundation;
@import Social;
@import MobileCoreServices;

@interface SLComposeViewController (FBMP4Video)

- (BOOL)addVideoURL:(NSURL *)url;

@end

@implementation SLComposeViewController (FBMP4Video)

- (BOOL)addVideoURL:(NSURL *)url {
    NSItemProvider *itemProvider = [[NSItemProvider alloc] initWithItem:url typeIdentifier:(NSString *)kUTTypeMPEG4];

    NSExtensionItem *extensionItem = [NSExtensionItem new];
    extensionItem.attachments = [NSArray arrayWithObject:itemProvider];

    return [self performSelector:@selector(addExtensionItem:) withObject:extensionItem];
}

@end
```

Answer (score -1):

For swift:

```
shareToTwitter.setInitialText("This is my video")
shareToTwitter.addURL(NSURL(string: "ur video link"))//add your video url to it
self.presentViewController(shareToTwitter, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Hope it helps, happy coding :)